# Laravel - Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: laravel

Im making a view that shows the users and the companies they work for.

In my User model i return the view like this:

```
return view('users.index', ['users' => $model->all()]);
```

The model $model->all() is my User model.

Then in my index.blade file i loop through the data like this:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="mailto:{{ $user->email }}">{{ $user->email }}</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->created_at->format('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->company->name }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <div class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                                                @if ($user->id != auth()->id())
                                                    <form action="{{ route('user.destroy', $user) }}" method="post">
                                                        @csrf
                                                        @method('delete')

                                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('user.edit', $user) }}">{{ __('Edit') }}</a>
                                                        <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" onclick="confirm('{{ __("Are you sure you want to delete this user?") }}') ? this.parentElement.submit() : ''">
                                                            {{ __('Delete') }}
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>    
                                                @else
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('profile.edit') }}">{{ __('Edit') }}</a>
                                                @endif
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

But when i try to show $user->company->name i get the following error:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

I tried debugging by using dd($user->company) and it showed all the company information of the company connected to the user. Then i tried dd($user->company->name) and it showed the company name.

I dont understand why i cant just show $user-company->name without getting the error but when i dd($user->company->name) it shows the company name.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: It seems User modal have a relation with Company. And I guess one of your user object does not have company info. while you dump all user objects did you check company exist for all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably shows an error because one of your users doesn't have a company. The first one of your loop has one, that's why when you `dd($user->company)`, you see a company. But it doesn't mean the second or third has one. You can do a if statement in order to catch any `null` company. Something like

```
if($user->company == null){ 
    dd($user); 
}
```

Alternatively, you can just do `dd($users->pluck('company','id'));`, which will show you a collection with the user id as key and related company (or null) as value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `optional()` helper to solve this. There are users who don't have companies. SO you can display them like this `optional($user->company)->name` and you will not get an error if a user does not have a company

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get relationship object value might be chances are there you will get this type of error. Due to there is some user who doesn't have company detail.

Just try below code.

```
{{ @$user->company->name }}
```